# Unable to install serverless using atlassian/default-image

Tags: npm, bitbucket, serverless-framework

I have a serverless application and I'm trying to use Bitbucket pipeline to create a build,
I'm using `atlassian/default-image:3` image for the Pipeline image,
It comes pre installed with node and few other useful libraries.

The pre installed Node and npm versions are as follows - 
Node - v14.17.5
npm - 6.14.14

While trying to install serverless using the command -
`npm install -g serverless`
I'm getting the following error -

```
npm WARN deprecated querystring@0.2.1: The querystring API is considered Legacy. new code should use the URLSearchParams API instead.
npm WARN deprecated querystring@0.2.0: The querystring API is considered Legacy. new code should use the URLSearchParams API instead.
npm WARN deprecated superagent@7.1.6: Please downgrade to v7.1.5 if you need IE/ActiveXObject support OR upgrade to v8.0.0 as we no longer support IE and published an incorrect patch version (see https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent/issues/1731)
/root/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.5/bin/serverless -> /root/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.5/lib/node_modules/serverless/bin/serverless.js
/root/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.5/bin/sls -> /root/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.5/lib/node_modules/serverless/bin/serverless.js

> es5-ext@0.10.62 postinstall /root/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.5/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/es5-ext
>  node -e "try{require('./_postinstall')}catch(e){}" || exit 0

sh: 1: node: Permission denied

> serverless@3.25.1 postinstall /root/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.5/lib/node_modules/serverless
> node ./scripts/postinstall.js

sh: 1: node: Permission denied
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@~2.3.2 (node_modules/serverless/node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.3.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! serverless@3.25.1 postinstall: `node ./scripts/postinstall.js`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the serverless@3.25.1 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2022-12-14T06_11_03_877Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 0):

Check node version being used (node --version).  I use nvm and was currently switched to an older vesion of node and got same error. After installing and switching to node v19.3.0 (latest at time of posting) the nom install serverless worked.